# How to add a common view in all view controllers at the bottom above tab bar

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

I need to add a view that has some buttons and appears in all the view controllers. The view should contain a horizontal scrollview in which all the buttons are placed.

The view needs to be on top of the tab bar. Similar to the one in the image[The player in the apple music application, on top of the tab bar in the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4spz.jpg)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

This is Swift 3 code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-100, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: 100)
    //window?.willRemoveSubview(view)

    //Add ScrollView to View
    let scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSize( width: view.frame.size.width*2, height: view.frame.size.height)
    scrollview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    scrollview.removeFromSuperview()
    view.addSubview(scrollview)

    //Add Button to Scrollview
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: scrollview.frame.size.width/3, y: scrollview.frame.size.height/2, width: 50, height: 30))
    btn.setTitle("Heloo", for: UIControlState.normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)
    let btn2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: scrollview.frame.size.width/2, y: scrollview.frame.size.height/2, width: 50, height: 30))
    btn2.setTitle("Hiiii", for: UIControlState.normal)
    btn2.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)
    scrollview.addSubview(btn)
    scrollview.addSubview(btn2)

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
    window?.bringSubview(toFront: view)

    return true
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, but how can i hide this view in certain view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to place the view, that needs to show on top of all controller's views at all times of running application, **add** **`subview`** to **`window`** in your App delegate.

**Pros:**

- it's fast if done proplerly
- brevity of code

**Cons:**

- needs you to make your own delegates (methods resposible for actions 
  with buttons)
- harder work with constraints for autolayout
- lot if design work
- hard do handle the situation, when you want to hide/show that bar, or just to hide it in certain view controllers

**OR:**

If you just need to extend UITabBar with ability to scroll , better would be to set tabbar conforming tabbar delegates and extend it using some library, for example:

https://github.com/kumapo/ScrollableTabs

**Pros of using library:**

- already prepared delegates
- issues with usage are well debugged

**Cons:**

- installation works

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I know it is hard to handle a situation where view should be hidden in certain view controllers, but if you have any idea about how to handle this situation,please let me know.

Comment: Your question has been put on hold anyway, so according to rules you should specify as much as possible you want to achieve as well as post what you've tried first. I meant to help you but rules are important.